# How to connect Sybase database using Java code in NetBeans?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, sybase

I want to connect remote `Sybase` from my `Java` code written in `NetBeans`. So far I have prepared a code as below:

```
public static void connect()
{
   String host = "192.168.150.11";
   String url = "jdbc:sybase:Tds:"+host+":4100";
   String username = "sa";
   String password ="";
   SybDriver sybDriver = null;
   Connection conn;

   try 
   {
      sybDriver=(SybDriver)Class.forName("com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver").newInstance();
      System.out.println("Driver Loaded");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
      Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from zxdbl_888..account_0");
      rs.next();
      System.out.println(rs.getString(2));

   } 
   catch (InstantiationException ex) 
   {
      Logger.getLogger(Offline_charge.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   } 
   catch (IllegalAccessException ex) 
   {
      Logger.getLogger(Offline_charge.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   } 
   catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) 
   {
      Logger.getLogger(Offline_charge.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   } 
   catch (SQLException ex) 
   {
      Logger.getLogger(Offline_charge.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
}
```

and the error I got is:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver
```

I have loaded `jconn3.jar` library.

Comment: Raazan Kurunju - if the answer was helpful for you upvote it. If it was the solution for your prolem - upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 5):

Install the `Sybase` drivers via a Java application.

[Sybase: Installing jConnect for JDBC](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32179.0707/html/jconnig/BABIEGCG.htm)

Comment: I have installed jconnect 7 and added jconn4.jar....but in this jar file...com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.sybDriver is not listed

Comment: it is SybDriver not sybDriver

Comment: oh sorry..ya i have used SybDriver. In jconn4.jar package...i couldn't find com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver

Comment: I know the post is pretty old, the link shared is not working today. Is there any other way to connect to sybase like any open source client ?