# sybase java DB connection issue

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase

I want to create sybase DB connection in java application.
I've added jconn4.jar to my project, but when I'm connecting to DB in code I have exception `ClassNotFoundException: com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver`.
My connection:

```
SqlConnect() {
    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("SQL exception  " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And also

```
public void connect() {
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sybase:Tds:localhost:5000", "DBA", "sql");
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        } catch (SQLException e) {

        }
    }
```

I want to connect to demo PowerBuilder database, with params:

```
DSN=EAS Demo DB V125;UID=dba;PWD=sql
```

What I'm doing wrong?
**ADDED**
Also when I'm trying to create database connection via intelij database work plugin i also have the same error.

Comment: have you installed the driver ?

Comment: @John Joe. Yes, I downloaded .jar file and added it to project in Intelij Idea

Comment: You should **never** call `DriverManager.registerDriver` yourself. This method needs to be called by the driver itself when it is loaded.

Comment: The error `ClassNotFoundException` means that the driver is not on the classpath, or you are using the wrong class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the other jdbc type driver resoled my problem - I connected sajdbcX driver and changed connection string:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlanywhere:uid=DBA;pwd=sql");
```

So, also thanx  Mark Rotteveel for advice - I removed driver register code as redurdrant.
And thank all for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have respected jars included on your classpath.
The following works for me:

Use `Class.forname` to load the drivers

Recommended Approach:

```
Class.forName("sybase.jdbc.sqlanywhere.IDriver")
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlanywhere:uid=DBA;pwd=sql");
```

Another way around:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver((Driver) Class.forName("sybase.jdbc.sqlanywhere.IDriver").newInstance());
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlanywhere:uid=DBA;pwd=sql");
```

The following link will help you in installing drivers:
[How to connect Sybase database using Java code in NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740386/how-to-connect-sybase-database-using-java-code-in-netbeans)

Comment: Yes, I've printed system property  java.class.path and my jar presents there. That type of driver register also  throws ClassNotFoundException

Comment: Are you using Class.forName() for loading drivers?

Comment: Yes, that is my current code: `DriverManager.registerDriver((Driver)Class.forName("sybase.jdbc.sqlanywhere.IDriver").newInstance());`

Comment: first:
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sybase.jdbc.sqlanywhere.IDriver` and the second, when program connects to db ` No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlanywhere:uid=DBA;pwd=sql`

Comment: The only reason for this exception is jvn is unable to find the drivers on the classpath. Also I have updated my ans

Comment: thanx, but it doesn't help, because link in Sybase documentation is unreacheable, I've updated my question too

Comment: You should **never** call `DriverManager.registerDriver` yourself. This method needs to be called by the driver itself when it is loaded.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel My bad,  i just updated used the code OP is trying to access